# Pandas - list with dict to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following output:

```
output = [{'test1': [('No Data', '[Auto] Clock in sync with NTP')]},
          {'test2': [('No Data', '[Auto] Clock in sync with NTP'),
                     ('No Data','Lambda - Concurrent Execution Limit')
          }]
```

Needed Dataframe:

```
                  test1                                            test2
0 'No Data', '[Auto] Clock in sync with NTP')     'No Data', '[Auto] Clock in sync with NTP'
1                                                 'No Data','Lambda - Concurrent Execution Limit'
```

```
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(output)
pprint(df)
```

Not working as I need. 
Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output = [{'test1': [('No Data', '[Auto] Clock in sync with NTP')]},
          {'test2': [('No Data', '[Auto] Clock in sync with NTP'),
                     ('No Data','Lambda - Concurrent Execution Limit')]
          }]
```

You can do this, but it is not a great idea to have lists be cells in a pandas dataframe.

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(o) for o in output], axis=1)
```